# Multiple Pages in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

My report has too many columns to display. How can I create multiple pages in a single Crystal Report?

I've tried 2 Page Headers and 2 Detail sections but it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult to implement, especially if you're looking to make your report printable on paper. Crystal usually expects to make multiple pages when there's too many *rows*, not too many columns.

You might be able to pull this off with clever use of subreports, one for Page A, and one for Page B, then forcing New Page After and alternating them. But that's dependent on what the rest of your report looks like. If each page still has multiple rows, I wouldn't try this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try subreports that you suggested.

Comment: @TheinWin Sounds good, let me know how that turns out. Don't forget to accept the answer if it indeed was helpful.